# Using WordPress' Theme Customizer to select page templates that update layout in the preview

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wasn't sure where to post this question..

I recently discovered WordPress' "Theme Customizer" and am using it to make the pages easier to update for clients. Rather than the standard way of editing each individual page, clicking update, and then visiting the page to see the changes, I like how the Theme Customizer automatically previews your changes on the right side.

I am trying to get an understanding of how far I can go with the Theme Customizer before I go all out on this...

I've created a "Home Page" setting/section/control pictured here:

[image]

And here is the code for this:

```
function prowordpress_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    // Settings, Sections, and Controls are defined here

    // HOME PAGE

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'home_page_text' , array(
        'default'           => 'This is the home page text',
        'type'              => 'option',
        'transport'         => 'refresh',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'prowordpress_content_customizations' , array(
        'title'       => __('Home Page', 'prowordpress'),
        'description' => __('Modify the Home Page', 'prowordpress'),
        'priority'    => 30,
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'home_page_text_control', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Home Page Text', 'prowordpress' ),
        'section'    => 'prowordpress_content_customizations',
        'settings'   => 'home_page_text',
        'type'       => 'textarea',
    ));


    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'home_page_template_select' , array(
        'default'           => 'test',
        'type'              => 'option',
        'transport'         => 'refresh',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'home_page_template_select',
            array(
                'label'          => __( 'Home page template:', 'blankwptheme' ),
                'section'        => 'prowordpress_content_customizations',
                'settings'       => 'home_page_template_select',
                'type'           => 'select',
                'choices'        => array(
                    'template_one'   => __( 'Template Layout 1' ),
                    'template_two'  => __( 'Template Layout 2' )
                )
            )
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'prowordpress_customize_register' );
```

You can see in the screenshot I've added a select menu for "Home page template"...

Is it possible I could set it up where the client can choose an existing "page template" from this select menu and then have the page preview/layout on the right hand side automatically inherit the page template settings and adjust the layout in real-time?

Again, I'm just trying to understand if this is feasible, and if anyone has tried something similar before. I realize this may require some AJAX or something along those lines.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. I have done this type of layout selection in my own theme.

in your php file you need to do something like this -

```
<?php if ( get_option( 'home_page_template_select' ) === 'template_one' ) {  

 get_template_part( 'layouts/template-one' ); ?>
```

I hope that helps.